# Java logger - apostrophe issues with tokens

Tags: java, logging, java.util.logging

I have some unexplained behavior with `java.util.logging`. Let's take a look at these two samples:

First:

```
boolean var = false;
log.log( Level.WARNING, "Cant {0}", new Object[] { var } );
```

output:

```
Cant false
```

---

Second:

```
boolean var = false;
log.log( Level.WARNING, "Can't {0}", new Object[] { var } );
```

output:

> Can't {0}

Why does the inclusion of an apostrophe ( ' ) causes the logger not to expand the token?

Comment: Also, the first output seems like it should be `Cant false`.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis log is a java.util.logging.Logger , you are right about the output, was posting in a hurry.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It appears that whatever logging mechanism you're using is using the `MessageFormat` class internally.  If so, then you'll need to escape the apostrophe character, because it's a single-quote character.  Single-quote characters are used to quote text that isn't meant to be interpreted.

[MessageFormat javadocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/MessageFormat.html):

> Within a String, a pair of single quotes can be used to quote any arbitrary characters except single quotes. For example, pattern string "'{0}'" represents string "{0}", not a FormatElement. A single quote itself must be represented by **doubled single quotes ''** throughout a String.

(emphasis mine)

Try

```
log.log( Level.WARNING, "Can''t {0}", new Object[] { var } );
```

This code:

```
MessageFormat mf = new MessageFormat("Can''t {0}");
System.out.println(mf.format(new Object[] {false}));
```

yields this output:

```
Can't false
```

Comment: Yes, this is it! I thought it had something to do with escaping but tried \' instead of double single quotes.

Answer (score 1):

`{` and `}` are also potentially problems. This is why [the NetBeans IDE hint to use message formats in log messages escapes these characters](http://hg.netbeans.org/main-silver/annotate/fcaaa60addf7/java.hints/src/org/netbeans/modules/java/hints/jackpot/hintsimpl/LoggerStringConcat.java#l204).

Besides

```
log.log(Level.WARNING, "Can''t {0}", new Object[] {var});
```

you can try simply and more readably

```
log.log(Level.WARNING, "Can’t {0}", new Object[] {var});
```

or just spell it out to begin with:

```
log.log(Level.WARNING, "Cannot {0}", new Object[] {var});
```