# Java Logger (java.util.logging.logger) not substituting variable

Tags: java, variables, logging

I was using the code below to log a Long variable,

```
logger.log(Level.INFO,"jQuery's active: {0}",active);
```

But on execution the variable was not substituted. I wrote another line above this one with different text as given below,

```
logger.log(Level.INFO,"Actual: {0}",active);
logger.log(Level.INFO,"jQuery's active: {0}",active);
```

On execution the substitution was working fine for the first log but still not the second one as shown below,

```
Sep 16, 2020 4:10:22 PM pages.pageUtils.CustomExpectedConditions$1 apply
INFO: Actual: 2
Sep 16, 2020 4:10:22 PM pages.pageUtils.CustomExpectedConditions$1 apply
INFO: jQuerys active: {0}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Java logger - apostrophe issues with tokens](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22670627/java-logger-apostrophe-issues-with-tokens)

Comment: Yes this answers my question, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

So what i found was that using `'` in the msg was causing the problem. Even while using `\'` i had the same problem. Although removing it fixes the issue i was wondering if there is any way i can use `'` in log?

Comment: You can escape the quote with a second quote. `"jQuery''s active"`